# I want to convert a Bitmap to a byte array for TensorflowLite

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I use Firebase's `ML Kit` for image recognition.

For `FLOAT 32`, it succeeded, but I don't know how to convert it to a `byte` array and can't use the byte model.

How should I convert it?

The model has the following format:.

```
[  1 224 224   3]
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
[1 2]
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
```

The values of the options specified for FIrebase are as follows:.

```
inputOutputOptions =
              new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                      .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.BYTE ,new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3})
                      .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.BYTE, new int[]{1,2})
                      .build();
```

I resized the Float data type as follows, but I don't know how to do it with the byte data type.

```
  public float[][][][] resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true);
    int batchNum = 0;
    float[][][][] input = new float[1][224][224][3];
    for (int x = 0; x < 224; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 224; y++) {
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
        input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
        input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
        input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
      }
    }return input;
  }
```

Comment: If you are using the model on Android, change the input/output data types to `float32` as it will be easier to parse and normalize images in Kotlin/Java.

Comment: Added code for the Float type to the question.
Is it difficult without Byte?
I built the model using Firebase's AutoMl and generated an Int 32 model.